# How do I CREATE default.aspx file for MVC 6 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default-document

I am new to MVC applications. I would like to host my MVC6 application on shared windows platform (hosting package). I have uploaded my project files via FTP onto the domain I created with my service provider. My project has a solution file (.sln) which point to my application and But unfortunately, the hosting platform requires my application to have a default.aspx file in order for it to be viewable online. Because of this I am unable to view the application online. How do I create a default.aspx file or get my application to show online?

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio one-click publish. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project then select Publish.

Case your code is correct, you should see your web application.

Comment: Thanks for the help but doesn't solve the problem. I am able to build and compile my application and view it locally on my box meaning my code is correct.  Even after publishing it, it still complains about missing default document as a default.aspx file is required. How do I get my application to generate the aspx file.

Comment: _default.aspx_ is the demo file of MVC, you can delete this file it's not important. The more important thing is- you must publish your website in order to get legit executable website. If you still want the default.aspx just create a file with the same name in the solution root folder.